# Unable to use dll file in my php application

Tags: c#, php, .net, dll, dllexport

I have a dll file which encrypts a string, I am trying to use that in my php application. For that I came to know that I have to use COM component, For that I have placed the dll in `C:windows/system32` directory and running the regsvr32 command but it is throwing error `entry point not found` also I try to do the same thing with `sysWOW64` directory but facing the same problem.
I have questions in my mind that am I approaching correctly to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't find an entry point because the assembly is a library. Only executable assemblies have an entry point.

Look here: [Using a DLL With PHP for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590637/using-a-dll-with-php-for-dummies)

Comment: So, I have to rewrite the dll?

Comment: Absolutely not. Transform it into an executable, provide the entry point (`void main(args[] string)` method) and you should be good to go. [Read on MSDN about the main method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx).

Comment: I have changed the link in the previous comment. If you need further help please use this new knowledge and write a new question.