# Integrated DLL File using PHP

Tags: php, dll

i have no idea with my solution, then i am trying to ask here, maybe someone can help me.

my problem was need and API Link like http://localhost:8080/api/functionA  to access or use Function in DLL file.

but i have no idea and i don't know if PHP can access DLL file or not.
or maybe i can to it with JAVA?

if can, how?

[i tried to read this question, but it still not help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590637/using-a-dll-with-php-for-dummies)

maybe someone ever face issue like me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the dll you require. but this can be done in following way

First, you need to register the dll with windows, use the following command in the terminal/Command Prompt

```
REGSVR32 YourDLL.dll
```

Then from your PHP code

`$dll = new COM(‘YourDLL.Functions’);`

`YourDLL` is the dll name an/or id and Functions is the object inside the dll that you can use, now `$dll` holds the dll functions

Now we can simply call the method inside the dll

```
$input = ‘Do some stuff on this’;
$output = $dll->DoStuffToString($input);
```

Comment: so, what must i do first is register my dll, all my dll ? is it for first time or i must register it every time if i want to use it?

Comment: why don't you try it