# call dll file in php using com function

Tags: php, .net, dll

```
$stack = new COM("dfs_dll.dll", "dfs_dll.Class1");
$stack->Push(".Net");
$stack->Push("Hello ");
echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
```

Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `dfs_dll.dll': Invalid syntax

Comment: So what do you do if you want to move your code to a linux server?

Comment: Are you sure the extension dll must be filled in the call to the com()... function?

Comment: but I call this file in php any suggestions for this dll

Comment: also add in dll extension in php.ini @juan

Comment: I'm not saying that the DLL must be added somewhere but in the COM function call should we enter "`dfs_dll.dll`" or "`dfs_dll`" as the first parameter...?

Comment: $stack = new DOTNET("dfs_dll", "dfs_dll.Class1");
$stack->Push(".Net");
$stack->Push("Hello ");
echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();

Comment: I think it would be helpfull : [dll with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590637/using-a-dll-with-php-for-dummies)